# How do I erase text from UITextField upon user touch in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a UITextField that holds the text: "Username". I want to erase the user name once the user has selected the text field for editing.

**Is there a better way than using the selector method?**

Here is the method I'm currently using, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
usernameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedUsernameField), for: .editingChanged)

func selectedUsernameField(sender: UITextField){
        print("selectedUsernameField")
        usernameTextField.text = ""
    }
```

Comment: This is what the `UITextField placeholder` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this case you should set the placeholder for `usernameTextField`.

```
usernameTextField.placeholder = "UserName"
```

It will disappear as user will start typing that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == usernameTextField{
         textField.text = ""
    }
}
```

It is called when the text field begins editing.

Although to use it you will need to make your class a `UITextFieldDelegate`

and also say:

```
usernameTextField.delegate = self
```

in `viewDidLoad`.